# Apollo client refetch inactive queries

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

I'm having a query that fetches a list with pagination. If I use `cache-and-network`, apollo first gets the cached list items, then gets the first page. It results in a flashing screen. If I use `network-only`, it stops, but every time I navigate, I get the first page of the list. I want to use the cached list. With `cache-first` it works fine.

However, when I'm trying to add a new item to the list, I obviously want to refetch it. Adding a new list item is in a separate component, and the list component is not rendered, and the list query isn't active.

Once the mutation promise resolves, I redirect to the list component, but it seems like `refetchQueries` runs before that.

I could make the list component be mounted to make the query active, but there must be an easier way to solve this - I mean it should be a common expected behaviour. Otherwise it would require to go with `network-only`, or implement some sort of state to know if a query should be refetched or not.

Comment: Did you find more information and/or a solution to your problem? I am in a similar situation.

Comment: I have a similiar issue.
 If after mutation, you change a hidden variable of the inactive query, will it work? when fetching again variables will change and then cache will miss and refetch.

Comment: I was facing a similar issue and I resolved it by updating the cache manually using apollo's update function. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#the-update-function

Answer (score 0):

I just took a look at the apollo graphql document. There are twos functions (refetchQueries, especially reFetchObservableQueries) allow us to refresh active query. It might help you to solve your challenge.

You can access to these functions by using the useApolloClient hook inside your component.

You also can refresh standby query by using includeStandby option.
Takes optional parameter includeStandby which will include queries in standby-mode when refetching.

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/core/ApolloClient/

Comment: the main is problem is that the query is not active at that time